# Loading events to fullcalendar from asp

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I've tried to load events from a json feed in asp: [example taken from here](http://jake1164.blogspot.com/2010/06/jquery-fullcalendar-and-aspnet.html)

The problem is that the webservice function, which is in a .aspx page, is never called. Firebug says it's all ok...
That's the code-behind:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.Load

End Sub


<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getEventos(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String
    Try
        Return CalendarioMensualDAO.Instance.getEventos(startDate, endDate)



    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("CalendarioMensual:getEventos: " & ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try
End Function
```

And that's the fullcalendar events call:

```
events: "Default.aspx/getEventos",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try to be more precise on how you call the code-behind method in the javascript part ?

Answer (score 0):

When you put the url Default.aspx/getEventos in your browser what do you get?

My php feed is   events:'diary_feed.php?user=me&bank_hols=1',
(comma at end because in the middle of the list of parameters)

and that page gives me
[{"id":"142454","title":"test's'f","auth":"authorised","start":"2011-01-14","className":"unp_authorised","editable":true}]